# How to draw two lines in java with swing and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, swing

so i am trying to make a program that will draw a line when you call the static void and it will send the coordinates of the line into an array to draw it in the panel class when i call it once it draws a line but when i call it twice it does not draw the first line only the second.

main class

```
package main;

import javax.swing.*;

public class VB {
    
    public static int[] POS_x1;
    public static int[] POS_y1;
    public static int[] POS_x2;
    public static int[] POS_y2;
    
    public static int PosCount;
    
    
    VB(){

    }
    
    public static void NewWindow(String Title, String LogoPath, int x, int y, int Width, int Height){
        
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(LogoPath); 
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setIconImage(image.getImage());
        frame.setTitle(Title);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setBounds(x, y, Width, Height);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }
    
    public static void DrawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

        POS_x1 = new int[256];
        POS_y1 = new int[256];
        POS_x2 = new int[256];
        POS_y2 = new int[256];
        
        POS_x1[PosCount] = x1;
        POS_y1[PosCount] = y1;
        POS_x2[PosCount] = x2;
        POS_y2[PosCount] = y2;
        PosCount++;
        System.out.println(PosCount);
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VB.NewWindow("window", "res/img/saullularphone.PNG", 100, 100, 500, 500);
        VB.DrawLine(0, 0, 100, 50);
        VB.DrawLine(0, 50, 100, 50);
    }
}
```

Panel class

```
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel {
    
    Panel(){
        repaint();
    }
    
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (int pos = 0; pos < VB.PosCount; pos++) {
            g2.setColor(Color.black);
            g2.drawLine(VB.POS_x1[pos], VB.POS_y1[pos], VB.POS_x2[pos], VB.POS_y2[pos]);
        }
    }

}
```

i tried drawing the first line then redrawing then drawing the second line but it didn't work and drew the second line

Comment: `for (int pos = 0; pos < 1; pos++) {` will only iterate once. Did you mean `for (int pos = 0; pos < VB.PosCount; pos++) {` ?

Comment: yea i spotted that and i fixed it but it only shows one of the lines

Comment: 1) You should NOT be suing static data and methods.  Any data needed to paint the lines should be defined in the class that does the painting. You will then also needs methods in this class to update the data. 2) Painting is NOT cumulative. If you want to paint multiple lines then you need to store the data for each line in the class that does the painting. Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for the two common ways to do this type of painting.

Comment: 3) Don't call you class "Panel". There is an AWT component with the class name so it gets confusing. Class names should be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using the `static` keyword anywhere but the `static` `main` method.

Here's a GUI that draws two lines.  You can add additional lines if you wish.

[image: Drawing Lines]

I created a Swing model using plain Java getter/setter classes.

I created a `LineSegment` class to hold all the parameters to draw a line.  I created a `DrawingLinesModel` class to hold a `List` of `LineSegment` instances.  You can use an array, but a `List` is more flexible.

I created a `JFrame` and a drawing `JPanel`.

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section. Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the additional classes inner classes so I could post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class DrawingLinesExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DrawingLinesExample());
    }

    private final DrawingLinesModel model;

    private final DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

    public DrawingLinesExample() {
        this.model = new DrawingLinesModel();
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(model);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drawing Lines");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private final DrawingLinesModel model;

        public DrawingPanel(DrawingLinesModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 640));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            for (LineSegment line : model.getLines()) {
                g2d.setColor(line.getColor());
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(line.getThickness()));
                Point sp = line.getStartPoint();
                Point ep = line.getEndPoint();
                g2d.drawLine(sp.x, sp.y, ep.x, ep.y);
            }
        }

    }

    public class DrawingLinesModel {

        private final List<LineSegment> lines;

        public DrawingLinesModel() {
            this.lines = new ArrayList<>();
            this.lines.add(new LineSegment(new Point(10, 10),
                    new Point(400, 400), Color.BLUE, 9));
            this.lines.add(new LineSegment(new Point(10, 400),
                    new Point(400, 10), Color.MAGENTA, 11));
        }

        public List<LineSegment> getLines() {
            return lines;
        }

    }

    public class LineSegment {

        private final int thickness;

        private final Color color;

        private final Point startPoint, endPoint;

        public LineSegment(Point startPoint, Point endPoint, Color color,
                int thickness) {
            this.startPoint = startPoint;
            this.endPoint = endPoint;
            this.color = color;
            this.thickness = thickness;
        }

        public Point getStartPoint() {
            return startPoint;
        }

        public Point getEndPoint() {
            return endPoint;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public int getThickness() {
            return thickness;
        }

    }

}
```